# Where to invest, that compounds interest more than annual?

Tags: stocks, investing, mutual-funds, bonds

Forgive my ignorance, I found this webpage [compounding weekly](http://www.meederinvestment.com/Public/default.aspx?wid=237&pid=237) and noticed the 0.24% 7 day rate.
I have heard that there were secure investment vehicles that compounded interest more frequently than annual but not real sure where to look.

What are some of the methods to get your money invested in a vehicle that compounds interest for frequently than annual?

Comment: `I have heard that there were secure investment vehicles` Where did you hear that ?

Comment: Stocks can have compounding on a daily basis but aren't quite that secure but I'm not sure if that is what you mean here.

Comment: @DumbCoder  any info I have is second hand and very possibly mis interpreted. I am in a situation now that I am looking very deeply into this, but not finding many resources to guide the n00bs.  Does this even exist? some sort of group or mutual fund that compounds more frequently like a stock? Or is this everybody's dream?

Comment: @JBKing  yes, stocks are just a tiny bit better than walking up to the poker tables. You at least get some history and plans for the cards you are holding, but still a flat out gamble.

Comment: Why do you care about the compounding period being less than annually? In general, this isn't helpful; you just offer a slightly lower interest rate to account for the difference in compounding periods. It works out to be the same.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton If you can be so lucky as to compound interest like a credit card, working in your favor, that shit adds up real fast.  I would LOVE to see compounding interest quarterly like some credit cards.

Comment: @doeJ, there's no benefit to a smaller compounding period if they just lower the interest rate to account for the difference. I'd rather see a 2% rate with annual compounding than a 1.9% rate compounded daily.

Comment: This is why rates are quoted in APY / APR terms.  The 'A' stands for annually, and includes the effects of any compounding over the year.  So you just want to compare investments by APY / APR returns.

Comment: @davmp  hmmm, just double checked, looks like you are correct. I guess 8% taxable is about the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Securities (things you can buy on the stock market)  that pay dividends usually pay every quarter (every three months), but some pay every month. (For example: [PGF](http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=PGF&p=D&yr=2&mn=0&dy=0&id=p00772102748) pays dividends each month.) IF you reinvest your dividends back into the stock then you will be compounding your return.

I use the feature at Scottrade to automatically reinvest the dividend each month. Using this feature at Scottrade incurs **no** commission for the purchases of the stock from the dividend. (saving on commissions and fees is, likely, the most important aspect of investing).

US Treasuries (usually) pay interest twice a year. There is no commission when using Treasury Direct.